# getview() in onResume() of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have below code in `onResume()` of a fragment.

```
getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
getView().requestFocus();
```

Since this code is invoked from inside `onResume`(), I am not using a null check.

So, I am not writing like below:

```
if(getView() != null){
getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
getView().requestFocus();
}
```

My question is: Is it OK to skip the null check in this case or shall I add code to null check?

In what cases  `getview`() will be null in `onResume`()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this lifecycle diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxv/android-lifecycle/master/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.png), `getView()` should never be `null` in `onResume`. However, being defensive wouldn't really hurt in this case. I might pull the view into a local reference though, instead of calling `getView()` three times.

```
View view = getView();
if (view != null) {
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: I believe the only case it could be `null` in `onResume()` is if you return `null` in `onCreateView()`.